# When does recv_exit_status() return -1?

Tags: python, unix, ssh, paramiko, robotframework

The documentation of `recv_exit_status()` in `paramiko/channel.py` says

> "If no exit status is provided by the server, `-1` is returned.".

In which situation can it happen that the server (`Unix`) is providing no exit status?

Answer (score 1):

For example, when the connection was unexpectedly dropped.

Comment: Are you sure? Or is an SSHException raised in this case?

Comment: I'm talking about the recv_exit_status() call in https://github.com/robotframework/SSHLibrary/blob/master/src/SSHLibrary/pythonclient.py. I have seen a case where execute_command() in abstractclient.py resulted in return_code = -1, stdout contained non-empty regular output and stderr was empty.